# Async Mocha: `done` called, but next test never runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, rethinkdb

I have an unconventional setup I can't change. It looks something like this:

1. test POSTs to server
2. server POSTs to blockchain
3. blockchain updates
4. syncing script updates the database

It is absolutely imperative that I do not run the next test until the test before it has completed that entire workflow, which typically takes 2-3 seconds. Here is an example of a test written for that flow with supertest and chai:

```
it('should create a user', done => {
  request(server)
    .post(`${API}/signup`)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .send(`{
      "email":"${USER_EMAIL}",
      "password":"${USER_PASSWORD}"
    }`)
    .expect(200)
    .expect(res => {
      expect(res.body.role).to.equal('user');
      expect(res.body.id).to.match(ID_PATTERN);
    })
    .end(_wait(done));
});
```

That `_wait` function is the key issue here. If I write it very naively with a setTimeout, it *will* work:

```
const _wait = cb => () => setTimeout(cb, 5000);
```

However, this isn't a great solution since the blockchain is very unpredictable, and can sometimes take much more than 2-3 seconds. What would be much better is to watch the database for changes. Thankfully the database is written in Rethink, which provides cursor objects that update on a change. So that should be easy, and look something like this:

```
var _wait = cb => () => {
  connector.exec(db => db.table('chain_info').changes())
  .then(cursor => {
    cursor.each((err, change) => {
      cb(err);
      return false;
    });
  });
};
```

This setup breaks the tests. As near as I can tell `done` *does* get called. Any console logs in and around it fire, and the test itself is logged as completed, but the next test never starts, and eventually everything times out:

```
Manager API Workflow:
  Account Creation:
    ✓ should create a user (6335ms)
    1) should login an administrator


1 passing (1m)
1 failing

1) Manager API Workflow: Account Creation: should login an administrator:
   Error: timeout of 60000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am using Mocha 3.1.2, Chai 3.5.0, Supertest 2.0.1, and Node 6.9.1.

Comment: I can't read all those arrow functions in a row. What would the `_wait` function look like with all those arrows? (not enough ES6 in my life!)

Comment: Why do you say "the next test never starts"? The output you show in your question shows that the next test *never ends*. I don't see anything in the output that indicates that it did not start.

Comment: @clay: It is a function that returns a function. So it would be equivalent to:
    `var _wait = function(cb) { return function() { connector.exec . . . }; };`

Comment: @Louis That is a fair point, but this problem exists regardless of what the next test is. You could copy and paste that user test twice, and the first one would pass, but the second one would time out.